# Проектирование API и наследование интерфейсов

Tags: c#, проектирование, интерфейс

Скорее всего, это достаточно глупый вопрос, но произошел глобальный "затык".

Итак: необходимо реализовать API и имплементацию подсистемы для большого проекта. Задача подсистемы - реализация синхронизации нескольких наборов данных разными способами (через веб/flash и, возможно, в будущем чего то еще).

При проектировании был выделен общий набор методов. Соответственно, пишем базовый интерфейс:

```
public interface IBase
{
   void A1();
   void A2();
   void A3();
}
```

Далее для каждого способа синхронизации были спроектированы свои интерфейсы:

```
public interface IDerived1 : IBase
{
   void B();
}

public interface IDerived2 : IBase
{
   void B();
   void C();
}
```

Для работы с API реализована фабрика:

```
public static class Factory
{
   public static IBase CreateDerived1() { ... }
   public static IBase CreateDerived2() { ... }
}
```

Соответственно, необходимо разделить имплементацию базового и дочерних интерфейсов так, что работая с объектом `IBase`, созданным с помощью фабрики, обращаться к методам, реализованным по-разному в зависимости от имплементации дочерних интерфейсов.

Как правильно это реализовать?

Comment: а почему в IBase у вас A1(), A2(), A3(), а в Derived B() и C()?

Answer (score 1):

Я может чего-то недопонимаю,

```
class Derived1: IDerived1{ ... }
class Derived2: IDerived2{ ... }

public static class Factory
{
   public static IBase CreateDerived1() 
   {
       return new Derived1();
   }
   public static IBase CreateDerived2()
   {
       return new Derived2();
   }
}
```

Получили два класса с разной реализацией и разные фабричные методы для создания объектов

```
IBase parent = Factory.CreateDerived1();
// вызовется реализация из Derived1
parent.A1();
parent = Factory.CreateDerived2();
// вызовется реализация из Derived2
parent.A1();
```

Использовали это дело.

Я всё правильно понял?

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы хотите после создания объекта обращаться к методам `B()` и `C()`, которых в `IBase` нет, то что Вам мешает сделать так:

```
public static class Factory
{
    public static IDerived1 CreateDerived1() { ... }
    public static IDerived2 CreateDerived2() { ... }
}
```

?

У Вас ведь даже и методы названы соответственно.